# Grails generic JSON handling of request and response

Tags: json, grails

i asked myself if there is a generic approach where i can parse requests in a generic way or add fields to a JSON response with every response sent.

I would like to receive and parse something like:

```
{
    transactionId:456, // every response contains this
    statuscode:1,
    content:{ // only content is changing
          {
              class:"org.something.test",
              id:123,
              name:"test",
              referenceIdToOtherClass:345
          }
    }

}
```

The contents of "content" should be converted e.g. to an instance of the given class.

The response should work also in such generic way (changing content, some fields always).

Would you reccomend a JSON marshaller, a Filter or something different?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the json to a map with JSON.parse

```
import grails.converters.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*; // package containing JSONObject, JSONArray,...

def o = JSON.parse("{ foo: 'bar' }"); // Parse a JSON String
assert o instanceof JSONObject // In this case, JSON.parse returns a JSONObject instance
assert o instanceof Map // which implements the Map interface
assert o.foo == 'bar' // access a property
```

and then you can pass the map to your constructor to create a new instance

from http://grails.org/Converters+Reference